# What URL used to unblock Java Security for local JNLP

Tags: java, security, java-web-start, jnlp

For the life of me, I can't figure out what to give Java Security as a "URL" to unblock an application launched by a JNLP file in my own file directory.

When I use my browser to call the JNLP file from a Java EE application deployed to my glassfish server, I have a "URL" so I can unblock that.

But for testing I'd like to be able to also just double click the JNLP file in my local PC directory to launch the app.

It can't be that difficult.  Double clicking the JNLP file does in fact begin  to launch the app.  Just Java blocks it.  And I just can't figure out how to unblock that kind of call  ... and can't find any reference to that simple a need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
file:///path/to/application.jnlp
```

?

Comment: That works.  Thank you.  [Embarassingly dumb ... I had one too few "/"]

Comment: Plus for other newbees ... "application" above really means the name of the jnlp file that launches the  application.

Comment: If it was helpful, please upvote and accept (after another 7 minutes, that is).  :)

Comment: I added a .jnlp to the end for clarity.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: My appologies, but I really am a newbee.  I assume there is someplace I can click to accept  the answer, but I can't find it. This really was helpful.

Comment: To upvote, just hit the outline of an up-arrow at the upper left corner of my answer.  To accept, hit the outline of a check-mark in the same area.